# Changing enabled to required throws an error in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

Changing enabled to required throws an error in gradle 7.5

```
> Configure project :
The Report.enabled property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Please use the required property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.reporting.Report.html#org.gradle.api.reporting.Report:enabled for more details.

 jacocoTestReport {
     reports {
-        xml.enabled false
-        csv.enabled false
-        html.enabled true
+        xml.required false
+        csv.required false
+        html.required true
     }
 }

> Could not find method required() for arguments [false] on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskGeneratedSingleFileReport.
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`required` is a property, not a method. This should help:

**Groovy DSL (build.gradle)**

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = false
        html.required = true
    }
}
```

**Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts)**

```kotlin
tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required.set(false)
        csv.required.set(false)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}
```

See: [JaCoCo Report configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_configuration)

Comment: Getting errors on 8.0.2 with `xml.required = true` (Could not find method required() for arguments [true] on Report xml of type org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskGeneratedSingleFileReport.)

Comment: @TasosZervos Just tested with Gradle 8.0.2. `xml.required = true` just works fine. Syntax is correct as per [Docs: JaCoCo Report configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_configuration).

Comment: Correction (I couldn't edit the comment when I've noticed) - I am using version 8.2.1.
I will try again and with 8.0.2 and see if it's related to this or something else.

Comment: It looks like the issue for me was only related to IntelliJ complaining about it.

Answer (score 10):

For gradle 8.2.1 I have found that previous answers also fail.

This has worked for me:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required.set(false)
        csv.required.set(false)
        html.required.set(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any difference between required and enabled?

Comment: enabled doesn't appear to be available when running in gradle 8.2.1. I just upgraded gradle and `enabled` wasn't available. this answer works for me.

Comment: @inquisitive
See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.reporting.Report.html#org.gradle.api.reporting.Report:enabled

Enabled has been replaced by required

Comment: Perfect for gradle 8